# How to register COM from VS Setup project?

Tags: com, registry

I have marked my DLL as vsdraCOM, and I can see it in the registry after installing, but my application does not see the COM interface until I call RegAsm on it manually.  Why could this be?

The COM registration does not work on Vista (confirmed myself) and on XP (confirmed by a colleague).
Using Visual Studio 2005 on XP.

Comment: What OS/Visual Studio version are you using to build the setup project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I have found a solution:

1. Run RegAsm.exe with the /regfile option to generate the registry entries.
2. Manually import the .reg file into the VS Setup project by viewing  the registry, right clicking, and choosing "Import..."

Comment: Nick.I used your method ,but still i have the same problem like guy who asked the question above.It appears in registry ,but the BHO plugin(IE add-on) is not added to the list of IE add-ons.Any idea?

Comment: @Tady If it appears as a registered CLSID, then you also need to tell IE about the BHO by adding a key with the CLSID to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Browser Helper Objects.