# Visual Studio Setup Project failing to add keys to registry

Tags: visual-studio, com, registry, setup-project

I'm creating a setup pacakage in Visual Studio 2008 to register a COM component and one of the actions is to add a few keys to the registry.

The odd thing about it is when I run the installer it creates the key hierarchy correctly but the last key in the hierarchy it creates has the wrong GUID... whereas its right in the installer... has anyone run into this or have any suggestions on what is going wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had the same (or a similar?) problem, my solution is here: [How to register COM from VS Setup project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12807/how-to-register-com-from-vs-setup-project)

Basically I just created the registry keys manually and added them to the setup project as a .reg file :)