# Use Visual Studio Setup Project to automatically register and GAC a COM Interop DLL

Tags: .net, interop, gac, setup-project, regasm

I've created a .NET assembly for COM interop and it is working well on my development machine.  I'm currently trying to figure out how to deploy the DLL to a target machine using Visual Studio's "Setup Project."  How can I use the VIsual Studio setup project to do the following things:

- Register the assembly (currently using `regasm`).

  - The assembly needs to be registered successfully <strike>and the type library (.tlb) needs to be registered successfully</strike>.
  - [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239465/how-to-register-a-net-ccw-with-regasm-from-a-visual-studio-2008-setup-project/1883517#1883517) suggests scrapping `regasm` in favor of custom code.  I this is a good idea? If so, how does this code get included in the setup project?
  - [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12807/how-to-register-com-from-vs-setup-project/14604#14604) suggests using the `/regfile` command of `regasm` and then using the import tool on the Registry in the Setup Project.  Will this work?
- Install the assembly in the GAC (currently using `gacutil`)

  - I'm aware of the "Global Assembly Cache Folder" in the "File System on Target Machine."  Is there anything special I need to do in including the assembly in the setup project?

Any other advice or concerns would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Gacutil.exe won't be available on the target machine.  Not a problem, MSI can get the job done.  Right-click "File System on Target Machine", Add, GAC.  Right-click that added folder, Add, Project Output.  That ensures the assembly is gac-ed.

It can also register the assembly like Regasm.exe does.  Set the Register property of the project output reference to vsdrpCOM.

Comment: Will the register property being set to `vsdrpCOM` automatically create and register the .tlb file as well? If not, how do I include the .tlb in the set up project (it doesn't seem to like being shared in the GAC folder in the setup project)?

Comment: That's a great point.  I got so used to typing `regasm /tlb...` that I just assumed I would need it, but you bring up a great point - the client machine's won't be writing code against these assemblies.  Much thanks.

Comment: To answer Ben's question in his comment, using vsdrpCOM *will* automatically create and register the .tlb file.

Comment: So what You are saying is that just setting register property to vsdrpCOM does exactly the same as the whole long solution in here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/239465/how-to-register-a-net-ccw-with-regasm-from-a-visual-studio-2008-setup-project/1883517#1883517 if so, then absolutely brilliant!

Comment: To conifrm: to make the Regasm automatic both steps from Hans Passant answer needs to be done.

Comment: I got tlb generated only into the Debug folder. What might be the reason? Everything works fine under Debug installer, under release there is no .tlb file generated by installer

Comment: Thanks @Hans, it really saved me today, was unable to figure out why the COM interop dll is not working after making installer.