# Register .NET DLL for COM Interop in Visual Studio Setup and Deployment project

Tags: .net, com-interop

I'm trying to register a dll for COM Interop and have the usual issue of it working on my dev machine but not our test server.  I'm attempting to do this in VS2008 using a Setup & Deployment project. I'm then trying to consume the library from classic ASP. The target machine is windows 2003 with SP2, IIS6.

Specifically I'm trying the method suggested by Hans here:

[Use Visual Studio Setup Project to automatically register and GAC a COM Interop DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3087063/use-visual-studio-setup-project-to-automatically-register-and-gac-a-com-interop-d)

Where he says "Set the Register property of the project output reference to vsdrpCOM."

As well as having this set I have the [assembly: ComVisible(true)] in the assemblyInfo of the project in question and the "Register for COM Interop" checkbox ticked.

Finally I have also strongly signed it and added to the GAC in the Setup and Deployment project.

The error I get in ASP is

```
Server object error 'ASP 0177 : 800401f3'

Server.CreateObject Failed
```

Oddly enough I can reference the registered library in Excel on the server in question and it works fine.  So it seems to be registered correctly.

Anybody have suggestions on other things I may have missed?

EDIT: Sorry more details added.

Comment: Document what you *know*.  What does the error say?  What kind of machine is it?  What do you see when you use SysInterals' ProcMon?  What is in the registry?

Comment: Sorry, more details added.  I'll see if I can get ProcMon and some output from that.

Comment: If you can create it with Excel then installation is not the problem.  You didn't talk about the machine, does it run a 64-bit operating system?

Comment: The target machine is windows 2003 with SP2, IIS6, x86 (32 bit).  I temporarily added the account that the application pool is running under to the local administrators to make sure if wasn't a permissions issue, but the problem persists.

Comment: Any suggestions on what do look for in ProcMon?  I'm seeing a bunch of "RegOpenKey" operations, with result "NAME NOT FOUND" but am unsure of what to look for here.

Comment: Thanks for the help Hans, I upvoted your answer in the linked question in lieu of something I can reasonably upvote here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue - the deployment project automatically has the "Just Me" option checked when doing the installation. Uninstalling and reinstalling with "Everyone" seems to have worked. Silly mistake.