# Deploying .net library for COM

Tags: .net, com

I've built a class library and registered it for com access using visual studio build options. This library will be accessed by excel VBA. How do I create an MSI to instal this on another computer that will be using the same excel file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MSI can get the job done. Right-click "File System on Target Machine", Add, GAC. Right-click that added folder, Add, Project Output. That ensures the assembly is gac-ed.
It can also register the assembly like Regasm.exe does. Set the Register property of the project output reference to vsdrpCOM.`

[Use Visual Studio Setup Project to automatically register and GAC a COM Interop DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3087063/use-visual-studio-setup-project-to-automatically-register-and-gac-a-com-interop-d)