# Put assembly in GAC on installation

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2015, .net-assembly

I had a big problem installing our custom tab with macros in excel due to a "strong name required" error in visual studio. Finally we sorted out the problem by putting an assembly in the Global Assembly Cache before we installed the macro.

However, now every time I publish a new version with visual studio I have to manually put the assembly in the GAC with the command prompt, or the installation will fail. Does anyone know how to achieve this automatic when the macro is installed? Is it possible to declare it in the code somewhere, or in visual studio, that the assembly should be copied to the GAC before it continues with the installation?

I would really appreciate some help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: How are you installing it?

Comment: I'm publishing a new setup.exe file from visual studio and install it from there on windows 8.1!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use Visual Studio Setup Project to automatically register and GAC a COM Interop DLL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3087063/use-visual-studio-setup-project-to-automatically-register-and-gac-a-com-interop)

Comment: Yes, it is. Thank you! We solved it by changing the "Embed Interop Types" to True :) Maybe this thread should be deleted.